# AppEngine/Nodejs: The application instance never went healthy

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am not able to deploy my app anymore, it get's shutdown immediately after deployment.
From the logs I get that it's health check related.

Here are some relevant logs I found :

```
A 2020-05-22T15:55:21Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://172.17.0.6/

A 2020-05-22T15:55:21Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from 

A 2020-05-22T15:55:21Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public

A 2020-05-22T15:55:21Z [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /

A 2020-05-22T15:55:21Z Starting the development server...

A 2020-05-22T15:55:21Z 

A 2020-05-22T15:55:22.211067914Z The application instance aef-default-20200522t234909-d5wt in version 20200522t234909 never went healthy. 
A 2020-05-22T15:55:22.338883Z App container has crashed! 
A 2020-05-22T15:55:49.977830886Z Unhealthy sidecars detected: gaeapp 
  undefined
A 2020-05-22T15:58:34.689678907Z ------------------------VM aef-default-20200522t234909-d5wt shutdown initiated----------------------- 
A 2020-05-22T15:58:34.689678908Z Current app health: 0 
A 2020-05-22T15:58:35.422734975Z Beginning service lameduck. 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589031Z Triggering app shutdown handlers. 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589032Z /var/lib/flex/vm_runtime/vm_shutdown.sh: line 82: should_call_ah_start_stop: command not found 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589033Z Sending SIGTERM to app. 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589034Z Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 409c3b85bb978322c522a5e6fe0fc3a5e80fa4eae9df306fdb224d52669989ab: Container 409c3b85bb978322c522a5e6fe0fc3a5e80fa4eae9df306fdb224d52669989ab is not running 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589035Z Sending SIGKILL to app. 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589036Z Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 409c3b85bb978322c522a5e6fe0fc3a5e80fa4eae9df306fdb224d52669989ab: Container 409c3b85bb978322c522a5e6fe0fc3a5e80fa4eae9df306fdb224d52669989ab is not running 
A 2020-05-22T15:59:00.781589037Z App shutdown handlers done.
```

My app.yml :

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
 - url: /
   static_files: build/index.html
   upload: build/index.html

 - url: /(.*)
   static_files: build/\1
   upload: build/(.*)
```

I don't understand why this is suddenly happening.
I read somewhere it could be memory related, so I doubled the memory from 2 to 4GB without effect (It used to work well with 2GB)

Many thanks

Comment: So let me see if I got this correct, the previous version works perfectly. Then you updated the app and started to get this message when trying to deploy?
So if you go back to the previous version everything works as expected?

Comment: Yes I just managed to deployed an older version successfully.
Since it's just a standard nodejs + the packages that goes with it, my reasoning is that in the worse case scenario nodejs would return some kind of error and not be able to produce the html/js. 
However the log complains about health check and how the application instance never went healthy and then triggers a shutdown.
I am new to this and I am assuming that the health check is independent from my application.

Comment: Ok so I created a project from scratch : `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript)
Then ran the `gcloud app deploy` command with above app.yml and got the same error. So somehow it's related to the latest version of bootstrap/react/typescript

Comment: The app deployed on the app engine flex doesn't start because of health check issues, but deployed on the app engine standard works (nodejs10). 
I am going to switch to standard env from now on (`https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments`)

Comment: can you confirm that the health checks are enabled correctly on the flex version?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks

Comment: I didn't do anything in particular on the health checks. It used to work and suddenly it didn't.

It seems related to this warning from the doc :
Warning: Legacy health checks using the /_ah/health path are now deprecated, and you should migrate to use split health checks.

Since I am happy migrating to the standard engine and it cost less money, I didn't dig further on this.